# Bootstrap navbar collapsed vertical going off screen 'cuz the size of the content on the nav-pills are too big

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, collapsable, nav-pills

So, I have a navbar collapse vertical on the left part of my page, when I click the nav-pills the menu content shows just under them as it should, however, there's too much info and it's going off screen, I have a pill with like 13 elements on it and it's on the very bottom of the page, almost all of it goes off screen, what could I do to make it go upwards or make the rest of the content fixed to the bottom of the container and the opened pill have a scrollbar so I could navigate through them.

The navbar is kinda like this: http://www.bootply.com/0TBt8gDdsr

i need the other pills to NOT go off screen, and the menu inside any of them to have at least a scroll bar or kinda of a little list that I could navigate through without taking too much space of the page, does anyone know how could I do that ? Thanks.

P.S:Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You could reduce padding, and why is the nav link height 55px?http://www.bootply.com/WFi3bCJ6IT

Comment: Because it looks better in the full page and changing the padding on my actual code doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want some additional tinkering to make the transition smoother, but to address only the issue of the large menu, apply the following CSS:

```
#cadastros-menu {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This will cause your first menu (the one with 10+ links) to have a fixed height and a scrollbar.  Unfortunately Bootstrap's JS does fire to have it expand down all the way and then it jumps back up to the fixed height.

In addition, you'll need to adjust your `.nav`.  You'll want it to have a specified width, and you'll want to use `display: block` in lieu of `table-cell` so that you have full-width links.

The fixed width on `.nav` will help keep your dropdown menu's scrollbar from appearing on the far right of the screen.  The full-width links is just good UI.

Comment: Okay, the css works perfectly, but i didn't get why to use the display:block instead of table-cell, when i change it the text go up, it looks weird here, also, do you know any way to make the menus open upwards ? Thanks

Comment: `block` will make your primary links take up 100% of the width.  Right now they take up only enough space as needed by the link title and relevant padding.   You can try using `. dropup` to see if that works; it is a valid Bootstrap class but I don't know if it will function in this use case.